# Android SQLite Query ( i want to parse General Sql query)

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have taken String value from a EditText . And a button to submit query.

```
String sql=editQuery.getText().toString();// SELECT * FROM employees

StringBuffer finalDataq=new StringBuffer();

Cursor cur = dbHelper.rawsqlquery(sql);

for(cur.moveToFirst();!cur.isAfterLast();cur.moveToNext()) {
    finalDataq.append(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.ID)));
    finalDataq.append(" - ");
    finalDataq.append(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.FIRST_NAME)));
                    finalDataq.append(" - ");
    finalDataq.append(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.LAST_NAME)));

    finalDataq.append(" - ");
    finalDataq.append(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.ADDRESS)));

    finalDataq.append(" - ");
    finalDataq.append(cur.getDouble(cur.getColumnIndex(MyDBHelper.SALARY)));
                    finalDataq.append("\n");

}
submittedQuery.setText(finalDataq);
```

**My `rawsqlquery()` function -**

```
public Cursor rawsqlquery(String sql) {
    return myDB.rawQuery(sql,null);
}
```

It is giving me right result . for example when i wrote select * from table_name ,it returned all row from table.

**But i want to choose particular column and i dont know how to do it.I want to write my query in editext and directly want to compile and get the result it will return cursor object(if i am not wrong). Then how would i choose column name to display my result, since the columns name are written in editText.
  for eg: SELECT id,fname from employees**

thank you in advance

Comment: if someone do notu nderstand then i will explain in comments

Comment: The thing is rawquery wriiten cursor objects.If i want to display all columns then it would be easy , but in edittext how would i know which column to display.can someone help with this ???

Comment: try `String[] names = cursor.getColumnNames();` and then get value of these columns only.

Comment: What are you trying to do, Fetch data from specific column and show instantly in EditText ?

Comment: @shree krishna . I m trying to fetch the query from editText and then i want to display data on a TextView. Since user is typing any sql query how would i know that these column are need to be display. My code is working if user select all row then i just have to print entire table which is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

try getting the column names retrieved by the `Cursor` using `cur.getColumnNames();` method

Remove your for loop and use the below code instead

```
Cursor cur = dbHelper.rawsqlquery(sql);
String[] names = cur.getColumnNames();
while(cur.moveToNext()) {
    for(String name : names) {
        finalDataq.append(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(name)));
        finalDataq.append(" - ");
    }
    finalDataq.append("\n");
}
```

Comment: Great...if this answer is helpful then close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to fetch all the column names as array and set it to `AutoCompleteTextView` giving user a choice menu. Like here you have `AutoCompleteTextView` called `actv`.

```
actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
```

Fetch all column names using

```
Cursor dbCursor = mDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
String[] columnNames = dbCursor.getColumnNames();
```

And then set the `adapter` to `actv`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,columnNames);
actv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This way user will get chance to choose the column names. Hope it helps.